# Angular 5 Headless Browser unittesting

Tags: unit-testing, karma-jasmine, ubuntu-16.04, angular5

I am running unit test using karma, jasmine with Angular 5. As I am deploying on a server we are running them using HealdessChrome.

Everything is working fine on my local computer. However, It's getting stuck on the ubuntu server.

> 05 03 2018 07:43:02.132:INFO [HeadlessChrome 64.0.3282 (Ubuntu 0.0.0)]: Connected on socket 9NdPfrccf8iYNlPrAAAA with id 56814881
>   05 03 2018 07:45:21.364:WARN [HeadlessChrome 64.0.3282 (Ubuntu 0.0.0)]: Disconnected (1 times)
>   HeadlessChrome 64.0.3282 (Ubuntu 0.0.0) ERROR
>     Disconnectedundefined

For information, it's working using Firefox Headless.

Thank you for your help!